# iphone Some Images in table are automatically rotated

Tags: iphone, uiimageview

I have database with photos in album table. I get all images in array and show in table.
Problem is few images are rotating by 90 degree.

Here is what in cellForRow method.

```
AlbumInformation * temp=[albumInfoArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.albumPicImageView.image=temp.albumPictureClass;
return cell;
```

I get all images but few rotates.

Please help.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UIImage have an assign  property "imageOrientation";
so this method may help you

- (UIImage *)fixOrientation:(UIImage *)aImage {

  ```
  // No-op if the orientation is already correct  
  if (aImage.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationUp)   
      return aImage;  

  // We need to calculate the proper transformation to make the image upright.  
  // We do it in 2 steps: Rotate if Left/Right/Down, and then flip if Mirrored.  
  CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;  

  switch (aImage.imageOrientation) {  
      case UIImageOrientationDown:  
      case UIImageOrientationDownMirrored:  
          transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, aImage.size.width, aImage.size.height);  
          transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, M_PI);  
          break;  

      case UIImageOrientationLeft:  
      case UIImageOrientationLeftMirrored:  
          transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, aImage.size.width, 0);  
          transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, M_PI_2);  
          break;  

      case UIImageOrientationRight:  
      case UIImageOrientationRightMirrored:  
          transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, 0, aImage.size.height);  
          transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, -M_PI_2);  
          break;  
      default:  
          break;  
  }  

  switch (aImage.imageOrientation) {  
      case UIImageOrientationUpMirrored:  
      case UIImageOrientationDownMirrored:  
          transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, aImage.size.width, 0);  
          transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, -1, 1);  
          break;  

      case UIImageOrientationLeftMirrored:  
      case UIImageOrientationRightMirrored:  
          transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, aImage.size.height, 0);  
          transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, -1, 1);  
          break;  
      default:  
          break;  
  }  

  // Now we draw the underlying CGImage into a new context, applying the transform  
  // calculated above.  
  CGContextRef ctx = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, aImage.size.width, aImage.size.height,  
                                           CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(aImage.CGImage), 0,  
                                           CGImageGetColorSpace(aImage.CGImage),  
                                           CGImageGetBitmapInfo(aImage.CGImage));  
  CGContextConcatCTM(ctx, transform);  
  switch (aImage.imageOrientation) {  
      case UIImageOrientationLeft:  
      case UIImageOrientationLeftMirrored:  
      case UIImageOrientationRight:  
      case UIImageOrientationRightMirrored:  
          // Grr...  
          CGContextDrawImage(ctx, CGRectMake(0,0,aImage.size.height,aImage.size.width), aImage.CGImage);  
          break;  

      default:  
          CGContextDrawImage(ctx, CGRectMake(0,0,aImage.size.width,aImage.size.height), aImage.CGImage);  
          break;  
  }  

  // And now we just create a new UIImage from the drawing context  
  CGImageRef cgimg = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(ctx);  
  UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgimg];  
  CGContextRelease(ctx);  
  CGImageRelease(cgimg);  
  return img;
  ```

  }

Comment: I am getting image orientation up for all images but some images are rotating I tried if(temp.albumPictureClass==UIImageOrientationUP){NSLog(@"Up");} All images printed this message

Comment: That means your image orientation all is "UP".So I think you can find the row which image is rotating by 90 degree,then rotating them by code......    My English is very bad,so I can't be sure you can understand what I said. --!Sorry!

Comment: Yes i got it. I have accepted your method. Its perfect.                 Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer following sample. In PhotoDisplayViewController.m test with following two cases you will get answer automatically no need to explain anyone.

**Case 1: with UIImageOrientation**

```
ALAssetRepresentation *assetRepresentation = [asset defaultRepresentation];

    UIImage *fullScreenImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[assetRepresentation fullScreenImage] scale:[assetRepresentation scale] orientation:(UIImageOrientation)[assetRepresentation orientation]];
```

**Case 2: with out UIImageOrientation**

```
ALAssetRepresentation *assetRepresentation = [asset defaultRepresentation];

    UIImage *fullScreenImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[assetRepresentation fullScreenImage] scale:[assetRepresentation scale] orientation:nil];
```

when you are reading from your asserts have some orientations like following

```
 UIImageOrientationUp,            // default orientation
    UIImageOrientationDown,          // 180 deg rotation
    UIImageOrientationLeft,          // 90 deg CCW
    UIImageOrientationRight,         // 90 deg CW
    UIImageOrientationUpMirrored,    // as above but image mirrored along other axis. horizontal flip
    UIImageOrientationDownMirrored,  // horizontal flip
    UIImageOrientationLeftMirrored,  // vertical flip
    UIImageOrientationRightMirrored, // vertical flip
```

SO please **download** go through this sample demo

**[MyImagePicker Demo](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/MyImagePicker/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010135)**

Note: 
if you want to display from all albums then you need to change code in RootViewController.m as following

```
NSUInteger groupTypes = ALAssetsGroupAlbum | ALAssetsGroupEvent | ALAssetsGroupFaces|ALAssetsGroupLibrary|ALAssetsGroupSavedPhotos|ALAssetsGroupPhotoStream;
```